# Loading image binary data returned by Ext.Ajax.request into <img> tag

Tags: html, extjs

This is a Sencha Touch + HTML question.

I retrieve image data from server using Ext.Ajax.request.

```
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/someimage.jpg',
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(res) {
            rec.set('imagedata', 'data:image/jpeg;base64{' + res.responseText + '}');
        },
        failure: function() {
            console.log ( 'Failed to GET image data ' + url );
        },
        scope: this
    });
```

Above res.responseText seems to contain the contents of the jpg file.

At a later point, I pass image data into an  tag in html, as follows,

```
<img src="{imagedata}" style="width:100%;"/>
```

Result:

Instead of the image, i see garbled text in image box. The garbled text is the content of responseText.

( PS... I am doing this to be able to store the image data locally into a sencha store. )

Comment: PS... I have also tried the following variation "  rec.set('imagedata', 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + res.responseText);  " with no change in output.

Comment: PS... the length of responseText is about 2500 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

I would just store the URLs of the images in the store and then create IMG elements on the fly like you do with the src set to the URL instead.

Keep it simple.